# How to remove blank spaces from an array and print first 3 letters from string of the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
       ['', 'Monday', '', '', 'Thursday', '', 'Saturday']
       OR,
       Monday,Thursday,saturday
```

I want output like;

```
       ['Monday', 'Thursday','Saturday']
```

AND,When i map this array I want to print only first 3 letters of the strings of the array like below;

```
       Mon,Thu,Sat
```

How to achive this????

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `filter(Boolean)` will make it more shorter

```js
let data = ['', 'Monday', '', '', 'Thursday', '', 'Saturday']
data = data.filter(Boolean).map(d => d.substring(0,3))
console.log(data)
```

Comment: Please vote to close obvious duplicates instead of answering them

Comment: @adiga yeah,will delete it later,since I have deleted 5 answers and reach the limit

Answer (score 0):

- use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove falsy values then,
- using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get first 3 characters as below

```js
const filtered = ["", "Monday", "", "", "Thursday", "", "Saturday"]
  .filter(Boolean)
  .map((day) => day.slice(0, 3));
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter`:

```js
var array = ['', 'Monday', '', '', 'Thursday', '', 'Saturday'];
var output = array.filter(x => x !== '')
                  .map(x => x.substring(0, 3));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Hey Tim, They have asked for starting 3 letters 

Comment: The OP changed the requirements.

Comment: oh my bad ... looks confusing